# Assign equals method to compare elements in ISet

Tags: c#, equals, set

I have a set like this

```
ISet<Declaration> set = new HashSet<Declaration>();
```

Declaration class is an external class of a library and it hasn't an equals method so if i do this..

```
set.Add(dec);
set.Add(dec1);
```

... my set will add both of them although dec and dec1 are "equals", so.. is there any way to set an equals method to ISet?

Thansk!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100.aspx) overload of the hashset constructor that takes an [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) in parameter.